# Erratic behavior with printf

Tags: c++, printf

Getting some weird results from printf.

```
double scale = 129 / 1024;

printf("%f \n", scale);
```

is printing either -0.000000, 0.000000 or some huge random number like 947634637338383939387378370000000000000.00000. It seems to randomly alternate between these each time i compile and run. There is a lot more to the program, but i can't figure out what could possibly be affecting printf in this situation. This is exactly how these two statements appear in my program. What have i done?

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is technically a duplicate question.  It could be a `printf`-related issue though I personally believe that it is a case of `int` division coerced to floating point.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker: That wouldn't be the case for a `double` variable tho. It wouldn't surprise me if that's an uninitialized value.

Comment: "%f" takes a float, not a dobule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing zero not erratic behaviour, it's showing you the result of the division of `129/1024`, and since both those numbers are integers, the result is 0. This is then assigned to the double.

Fix that problem by changing `129` to `129.0`, which makes it a `double` value.

The "large number" can't be explained from the code we can see. I'm guessing that there is MORE code than these two lines however, and there is probably something going wrong elsewhere that affects the result.

Comment: And how do you explain the other values he get?

Comment: I don't know - I'm afraid that's probably in the "rest of the code that we don't see". Or there's something wrong with the hardware.

Comment: @RanEldan: But feel free to point out where my above comment is wrong. I'm willing to learn.

Comment: I have no idea, that's why i asked. I'm willing to learn too :)

Comment: Newbie mistake it seems. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to print `0.000000` all of the time.  `(129 / 1024) = 0` for integer arithmetic.

Comment: And how do you explain the other values he get?

Comment: I honestly don't know.  I'm pretty sure that there is additional code not being shown or something of the like.  `double d = 129 / 1024` will *always* produce a value of zero.